# is it possible to slice a np array irregularly without a for loop and sum each row?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

question about slicing numpy arrays.

Say I  have an array:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).reshape(3,3)

[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[7 8 9]
```

and indices:

```
idx = [2,2,1]
```

and I want to get up to the index value for each row..i.e `[:2]` in first row, `[:2]` in second, `[:1]` in third. Also would like to sum the slices as I go.

I know I can achieve this doing the following:

```
for i,a in zip(idx,A):
    print(a[:i],sum(a[:i]))
```

output:

```
[1 2] 3
[4 5] 9
[7] 7
```

Is there anyway this could be achieved without a for loop? Main focus is to do the irregular slicing, the sum was just an arbitrary operation I want to perform.

Something like:

```
A[:,:idx]
```

just to give context to what I mean

Comment: i think your question needs more context, because in the example provided, you are getting the lower triangle and then summing horizontally, i.e. the result may be obtained by `np.tril(A).sum(1)`

Comment: it was just a random example... I want to provide a list of indexes (same length as the number of rows in A) and slice each row of A by the corresponding index

Comment: I changed the indexes so it's clear I don't want the triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a matrix of indexes & create a mask by checking if the index is in the required range.

```
idx = np.repeat(np.arange(0,3), 3, 0).reshape(3,3).T
row_limits = np.array([[2], [2], [1]])
mask = idx < row_limits
masked_A = np.multiply(A, mask)
# masked_A outputs:
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [4, 5, 0],
       [7, 0, 0]])
```

and then apply `sum` along `axis=1`

```
masked_A.sum(1)
# outputs: array([3, 9, 7])
```